# Simple, fast, secure KDE Linux distribution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, linux-distribution, operating-system

I'm new to Linux, still learning how Linux in general works, but before that I need some smart opinion from a person who knows this stuff already, so my question is very simple, what is the most basic linux distro that I can start working on right away [mostly some noob web developing stuff] but it has these qualities:

1. Simple
2. Fast
3. Runs KDE
4. Secure [private]

I heard that ***Ubuntu*** was not that bad, and then I see that they send my search history to Amazon servers, wtf? [wtf Canonical?] so, its not private, not cool, then I realise kde ***Kubuntu*** looks nice, but Im not sure if Canonical has anything to do with that distro, so Im scared, then I started researching ***centOS***, because they say its a clone of ***RHEL*** and rhel is pretty stable and private, but then I hear that it lags behind rhel for couple of months with security patches, and plus its server oriented distro, so yeah, theres that, and I look at ***Fedora*** too, but they say it has cutting edge software, but does that mean it has higher chances for security holes and its maybe complex to use cause of that?

So my question is simple, is there a distro, that is not greedy for money and sends my stuff from my pc to some other servers, its not like Im doing something really important, like rocket science, but I still value my privacy, it just feels strange if somebody has access to my data , wtf is that? a distro that doesnt require me to be Linus Torvalds to install it and operate on day to day basis, and that is not resource hungry and has a nice community of developers...

And is there some distro, that is just developed by few cool developers, not owned by any company, just there for people to use?

If you read this novel, thank you, and sorry...but your opinion from your experience would mean a lot to a noob like me, thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: It's much more fun to have hundreds of crappy distros.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I like your optimism, but still, no time sir...no time...

Comment: You could try a Raspberry Pi

Comment: re: search history, presumably that's just with the default Firefox install

Comment: [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com) is often the go-to distro for a Linux that “just works”. But I do not know about practical privacy concerns there. You might also consider [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) instead of Linux, with [TrueOS](https://www.trueos.org/) (formerly [PC-BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-BSD)) being the distro that “just works” with an easy installer, desktop built-in, and Linux compatibility layer. I suspect you may find greater care about privacy in the BSD world, but I do not know about practical privacy effects of various apps.

Comment: AFAIK sending searches is only happening in Unity's (and thus only in Ubuntu and not in Lubuntu, Kubuntu, etc) search thingie (IIRC it's called Dash)…

Comment: @wb9688 oh...I didnt know that, so its just Unity thing..cool, thanks for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubuntu is free, well maintained and has the KDE interface, has a very supportive developer/user community, etc. - I like it a lot and have yet to see any builtin adware, pay-per-whatever and I am reasonably sure that if it were sharing users data all over the place alarm bells would have been well and truly rung.

It is also a nice complete install and doesn't need to be maintained by a genius *unless you are trying to either run on very unusual hardware &/or perform very unusual operations*.

"Kubuntu is a trademark of Canonical Ltd." **but** the majority of the work on it is undertaken by the community.

Comment: Except for the code that sends data to the highest bidder, well, thats Canonical...oh ok, no prob then :D jk, thanks for your answer

Comment: @falcoperegrinus - Actually I am sure that I would have heard if there was any such code in Kubuntu - your ISP on the other hand almost certainly sends copies of all of the things you do online to at least one government. https://fixubuntu.com/ tells you how to opt out in Unity and specifically mentions that Kubuntu is not affected.

Comment: Thats why my ISP also likes my VPN heh...but yeah, I guess you are right, Im probably gonna go with kubuntu, but I have a question, what do you think about Fedora? you have any experience with it?

Comment: Been a while since I played with fedora there were some support issues shortly after the red hat split IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR**: As of mid 2017 in my opinion the best KDE Plasma distributions
>   are [OpenSUSE](https://www.opensuse.org/) [Tumleweed], [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/) and [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/).

[KDE project page](https://www.kde.org/) has a list of patrons on the bottom, among which are [OpenSUSE](https://www.opensuse.org/) and [Cannonical](https://www.canonical.com) who are directly maintaining their Linux distros and have largest impact on Plasma desktop.

[Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) right now is not the best distribution with Plasma desktop; the core team is developing [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/) now, which is a way better option if you want a deb-based distro.

Also, Plasma 5 works surprisingly well on arch-based systems, the most user friedly is arguably [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/). I personally use Manjaro KDE a lot, and I have no complains.

Comment: Neon is latest even unstable Plasma, put there for testers. It's [not even a distro](https://neon.kde.org/faq#is-it-a-distro). As for the Arch-based systems, no newcomer should mess with them. As for the "passionate" users, they surely love exactly what normal people must hate: the instability, the "not knowing what tomorrow brings" poetry of it.

Answer (score 0):

[MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/products/) has a very stable KDE Plasma version now. It is a very stable release, and although personally I prefer the Ubuntu base to the Debian one, MXLinux KDE clearly stays as a good choice under this question.

What is great about Ubuntu is the huge community and quick support that you get on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). Therefore **Kubuntu is the best choice in that sense**.

[Solus](https://getsol.us/home/) Linux has a KDE version now which I tested, it's mostly ok, but features a rather recent Plasma which may involve some instability for the moment.

Too bad there is no Linux Mint KDE anymore, although at the date of this question the last Mint KDE was well supported. [At the date of my first post under here it is still supported for one more month :))](https://www.linuxmint.com/download_all.php)